# Visual Studio 2017 Cordova 7.0 Missing Info.plist Key

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to publish Cordova application to ios stores and getting the error

```
Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

I am using `Visual Studio 2017`, `Cordova 7.0`, `ios 8.3.1`, `mac 10.x`

I have reinstalled the latest `Cordova Camera` or `Media plugins`.

I have used some other suggestions like plugin that updates the `info.plist` while building and also added some tags inside `config.xml` to reflect the required changes in `info.plist` but there no use.

I could not figure out how to resolve this. can somebody throw some light to resolve this.

Comment: How do you install the plugins in VS2017? Can you share your config.xml?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I install plugins from git using http reference path for latest versions of plugins. I can not copy the entire config.xml due to max char limitation to postings here. Any specific part you are referring to, I can copy paste. *-info.plist has entries as required. but the final output ipa if uploaded is throwing the above said error.

Comment: I asked how, not from where. I ask that before when you install them from cordova CLI you can use variables to configure such values

Comment: inside visual studio, a facility is provided to install plugins. I use that to install plugins. I don't use cordova CLI. if there are any values required for variables such as "Camera Usage Description" etc..while installing wizard asks values for them. This is how they will be installed.

Comment: And if they are not required, does it provide a way of adding them anyway?

Comment: your question is confusing @jcesarmobile. If they are not required then what would we give to them?

Comment: They are not required on install time because  when it was implemented it was allowed to provide an empty string and that is used when you don't provide the variable. Also multiple plugins require the same texts so you might have set it previously when you installed another plugin. But now Apple requires a non empty text, so you should set them on the config.xml or VS2017 should provide a way of setting variables that are not mandatory

Comment: I am not sure if all plugins are required to be reinstalled to latest version. Now I am finding it to be the need of it. I will check and post my comments. There is one plugin giving 404 error, which is background plugin but same goes away if we rebuild again.